# Unable to unpickle object with overwritten hash method

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to save an object with pickle and unpickle it later. The Object has just a single attribute, a list (of conflicts).

```
class Conflicts:
    def __init__(self, conflict_list):
        self.conflict_set = conflict_list
```

From another function I receive the list of conflicts which then is used to init a Conflicts().
While saving works fine, whenever I unpickle the file I get the error:

```
File "C:\Workspace\Bachelor\ws\cfgnet_org\src\cfgnet\launcher.py", line 99, in loadc
    conflicts = pickle.load(pickle_file)
  File "C:\Workspace\Bachelor\ws\cfgnet_org\src\cfgnet\linker\link.py", line 115, in __hash__
    obj_hash = hash("|".join([self.node_a_id, self.node_b_id]))
AttributeError: 'Link' object has no attribute 'node_a_id'

Each conflict contains a Link and the Link looks (simplified) like this:
```

class Link:

```
node_a: ValueNode
node_a_id : str
node_b: ValueNode
node_b_id : str

def __init__(self, node_a: ValueNode, node_b: ValueNode):
    if node_b.id < node_a.id:
        node_a, node_b = node_b, node_a

    self.node_a = node_a
    self.node_b = node_b
    self.node_a_id = node_a.id
    self.node_b_id = node_b.id

def __getstate__(self):
    return (
                self.node_a, 
                self.node_b, 
                self.node_a_id, 
                self.node_b_id
            )

def __setstate__(self, state):
    (
        self.node_a,
        self.node_b, 
        self.node_a_id, 
        self.node_b_id
    ) = state

def __hash__(self):
    obj_hash = hash("|".join([self.node_a_id, self.node_b_id]))
    return obj_hash`
```

just to include it, here is the **init** of the conflict in question:

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        link: Link,
        artifact: ArtifactNode,
        option: OptionNode,
        value: ValueNode,
        old_value: ValueNode,
        dependent_artifact: ArtifactNode,
        dependent_option: OptionNode,
        dependent_value: ValueNode,
    ):
        super().__init__(link)
        self.artifact: ArtifactNode = artifact
        self.option: OptionNode = option
        self.value: ValueNode = value

        id_string: str = old_value.id + "->" + self.value.id
        self.id: str = hashlib.md5(id_string.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

        self.old_value: ValueNode = old_value
        self.dependents: Set = set([(dependent_artifact, dependent_option)])
        self.dependent_artifact: ArtifactNode = dependent_artifact
        self.dependent_option: OptionNode = dependent_option
        self.dependent_value: ValueNode = dependent_value
```

but I don't where the problem could lie within conflict, so i focused on the link class.

I found similar problems on stackoverflow:

- [Pickle/dill cannot handle circular references if __hash__ is overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887394/pickle-dill-cannot-handle-circular-references-if-hash-is-overridden)
- [Can Pickle handle multiple object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433963/can-pickle-handle-multiple-object-references)
- [pickle and dill can't load objects with overridden __hash__ function (AttributeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75409930/pickle-and-dill-cant-load-objects-with-overridden-hash-function-attributee?noredirect=1&lq=1)
  but none of those helped me.

I tried to implement **getstate** / **setstate** aswell as working with **reduce**. I tried to get rid of anything that might call the **hash** function (so i tried to remove dicts and sets and turn them into lists).
I am very confused why this error occurs, since I provide the correct data for unpickling with **getstate** / **setstate**.

Also, in this project there is an object called network which contains links and when that object is pickled and unpickled there are no problems at all. This error only occurs when I try to save a conflict, but the error message points towards link.py. I would assume that providing **getstate** / **setstate** would be enough for pickle to recreate that object, but for some reason it can't restore a simple string and I'm at my wits end.

I could get it all running by modifying the **hash** method of link, but that might change the behavior of the tool so I would like to avoid that.